# KendoTreeView Checkbox Clear All

Tags: jquery, kendo-treeview

I am using KendoTreeView control for hierarchical data. Also I need to provide ClearAll feature where all other fields in form including selections made in KendoTreeView should be cleared. So I have written something like this :

```
 public ClearAll(): void {
        $('#myTreeView').find('input:checkbox').each(function (index,element) {
            $(element).prop('checked', false);
        });
            }
```

Though this clears all selected checkboxes from treeview, however after this if I check parent node again - child checkboxes does not get checked.

Also this behavior (child nodes not getting checked) happens for first time only, so if I uncheck and check parent node again - child nodes will be checked.

I simulated sample example for this issue :

http://dojo.telerik.com/@rahul_ec27/ALihu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML

```
<button id="btnclear" class="k-button" onclick="ClearAll();">Clear All</button>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
function ClearAll()
{
    $(".k-treeview .k-checkbox input").prop("checked", false).trigger("change");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting DataSource again will reset checks,

```
     function ClearAll(){

      $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").setDataSource([
                {
                    id: 2, text: "Kendo UI Project", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                        { id: 3, text: "about.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                        { id: 4, text: "index.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                        { id: 5, text: "logo.png", spriteCssClass: "image" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 6, text: "New Web Site", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                        { id: 7, text: "mockup.jpg", spriteCssClass: "image" },
                        { id: 8, text: "Research.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 9, text: "Reports", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                        { id: 10, text: "February.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                        { id: 11, text: "March.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                        { id: 12, text: "April.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" }
                    ]
                }
            ]);
  }
```